# Is there a way to use Materialize CDN with Next.js?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, materialize

I am building a Next.js application and would like to use Materialize CDN with it. In React, I would just add the CDN links in the `public/index.html` file and would be good to go. Next doesn't seem to have that and I am stuck on how to do this.

I have tried with

```
npm install materialize-css@next --save
```

And I import it into the `pages/_app.tsx` like so:

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import 'materialize-css'
```

When it is just the first import alone, it works well, but when I import the second one to add JS, it throws me this error:

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

Also, with this kind of import, I can't make any customization to the CSS which is why I would like to use the CDN. I have been at it for days with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it in the `_app.tsx` do it in a `_document.js` file. This file is where you augment the html and body tags in NextJS projects. It's important to note that it has to be a **.js** file, not .tsx.

This file is not present in your project by default and it is auto-generated by nextJS, but you can create it in the pages folder to override the default one and import the CDN there.

You have the _document.js template and more information in [the official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document).

Answer (score 4):

##### Using Materialize via CDN

As [Daniel mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69736029/1870780), you can add the CDN links in your custom `_document`, so both CSS and JavaScript get properly loaded in the browser.

```js
// /pages/_document.js

class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <Head>
                    <link
                        rel="stylesheet"
                        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"
                    />
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}
```

Because Materialize uses Web APIs internally, you'll need to access the Materialize instance attached to the `window` inside a `useEffect`. This prevents the `ReferenceError: window is not defined` error when the page gets pre-rendered on the server by Next.js.

Here's a small example of how to use Materialize in a component that renders a carousel.

```js
const MaterializeCarousel = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
        const instances = window.M.Carousel.init(elems);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="carousel">
            <a className="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1" /></a>
            <a className="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2" /></a>
            <a className="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3" /></a>
            <a className="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4" /></a>
            <a className="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5" /></a>
        </div>
    );
};
```

---

##### Using Materialize via npm package

Another option is to use to library through its npm package `materialize-css`.

You first need to import the global CSS, as you did, in `_app`.

```js
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
```

The JavaScript code can't be loaded here, as mentioned earlier it utilizes Web APIs that don't work on the server.

Instead, taking the same carousel component as an example, you should dynamically import `materialize-css` inside a `useEffect` so it's only loaded on the client-side.

```js
const MaterializeCarousel = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const init = async () => {
            const M = await import('materialize-css');
            const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
            const instances = M.Carousel.init(elems);
        };
        init();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="carousel">
            <a className="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1" /></a>
            <a className="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2" /></a>
            <a className="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3" /></a>
            <a className="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4" /></a>
            <a className="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5" /></a>
        </div>
    );
};
```